# python, how to write conditions in a function?

Tags: python, function, numpy, logic, conditional-statements

How to write conditions in a function (k_over_iq)?

```
dt_for_all_days_np=a numpy array of numbers.


def k_over_iq(dt):
    if dt !=0:
       return 0.7*(1-e**(-0.01*dt**2.4))
    else:
       return 1

 k_over_iq_i=k_over_iq(dt_for_all_days_np)
```

I get the following error:

if dt !=0: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Are you missing one level of indentation in the function?

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the observed result? Why are the two dissimilar?

Answer (score 1):

`if dt != 0:` won't work if `dt` is a `numpy` array.  The `if` tries to get a single boolean out of the array, and as the error message warns, that's ambiguous: is `array([True, False])` True or False?

To get around that in a vectorized fashion, two common ways are to use `where` or to use boolean indexing to patch.

*Method #1, `np.where`*

```
>>> dt = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>> np.where(dt != 0, 0.7*(1-np.exp(-0.01*dt**2.4)), 1)
array([ 1.        ,  0.00696512,  0.03598813,  0.09124601])
```

This uses the function whenever `dt != 0`:

```
>>> dt != 0
array([False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

and 1 otherwise.

*Method #2: boolean indexing to patch*

Compute the function everywhere and then fix the values that are wrong.

```
>>> b = 0.7*(1-np.exp(-0.01*dt**2.4))
>>> b
array([ 0.        ,  0.00696512,  0.03598813,  0.09124601])
>>> b[dt == 0] = 1
>>> b
array([ 1.        ,  0.00696512,  0.03598813,  0.09124601])
```

Comment: I see the problem. Is there away to add it into the defined function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  There's no reason you can't perform the above operations in `k_over_iq` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is the problem in your function.
I recommend you reading this: **[Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)**

```
def k_over_iq(dt):
    if dt !=0:
       return 0.7*(1-e**(-0.01*dt**2.4))
    else:
       return 1

k_over_iq_i=k_over_iq(dt_for_all_days_np)
```